# Value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'first_name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'UserAdmin', or an attribute on 'authentication.User'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add following code to `admin.py` to make sure that user's password created from django admin will be hashed.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin


class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    pass


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

But when i try i got following:

> <class 'authentication.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of
> 'list_display[2]' refers to 'first_name', which is not a callable, an
> attribute of 'UserAdmin', or an attribute or method on
> 'authentication.User'.

The User model looks like this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)

is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

balance = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def tokens(self):
    """" Метод получения токена """
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token)
    }

def has_delete_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
   
    return True if self.is_staff is True else False
```

Comment: Your `User` model has no `first_name`, or `last_name`...

Comment: You might also have to change the `form` and `add_form` attributes to your own forms (they use the default user model directly).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what if i don't want to have this fields in my model?

Comment: @AlexNikitin: you will need to alter all attributes where these fields are mentioned, so for example `list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff')`.

Comment: @AlexNikitin: but the problem is worse, since as Abdul says, you will also need to update the forms such that these no longer use these fields as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually I mention the forms because in their `Meta` they set the model as `model = User` (the user model from `django.contrib.auth`). The fields should not be much of an issue in these forms as they don't explicitly use the field names.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: well it makes a fixed connection to the `User` model of `django.contrib.auth`, so if it works with `__all__` (which `UserChangeForm` does), it will use all the fields of that `User` model, not the one here installed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes that is true (and also what I mean here), so we just need to override the forms and define our own `Meta` class.

Answer (score 2):

You make use of the `UserAdmin`, but in the [**`UserAdmin`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L40-L205), this works with fields like `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. that are *not* defined on your custom `User` model.

> ```
> @admin.register(User)
> class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     # …
>     fieldsets = (
>         (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
>         (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
>         (_('Permissions'), {
>             'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
>         }),
>         (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
>     )
>     # …
>     list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
>     list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
>     search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
>     ordering = ('username',)
>     filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
>     # …
> ```

You will thus have to rewrite the `fieldsets`, `list_display`, and `search_fields` such that these no longer mention the `first_name` and `last_name` fields. You can of course also alter you `User` model to include these fields, but right now there is simply a mismatch between the `UserAdmin` and your `User` model.

Furthermore as, [@AbdulAzizBarkat says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66929896/value-of-list-display2-refers-to-first-name-which-is-not-a-callable-an-a?noredirect=1#comment118308308_66929896), this model admin also has a `form` and `add_form`, which will include these fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following code of admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserCreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    list_display = ("email",)
    ordering = ("email",)

    fieldsets = (
        (
            None, {
                'fields': (
                    'email',
                    'password',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'balance',
                    'is_verified',
                    'is_active',
                    'is_staff'
                )
            }
        ),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None, {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': (
                    'email',
                    'password',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'is_superuser',
                    'is_staff',
                    'is_active',
                    'is_verified'
                )
            }
        ),
    )

    filter_horizontal = ()


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, I am answering the question so that it will help others. In the user model that extends the AbstractBaseUser, a method should be added with the name of the field to display in the class that extends admin.ModelAdminadmin as:

> 

```
@admin.display(ordering='user__first_name')
    def first_name(self):
    return self.user.first_name
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me how that would fix the problem: the user model has no `user` field, so `self.user` will raise an attribute error, and for the same reason, using `.order_by('user__first_name')` will not work either.